# Determine the general notation of the given progression: 2100, 2121, 2144, 2169...

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question provided sequence progression of 2100,2121,2144,2169 and so on. The question ask me to find the sequence in the notation of {a<sub>r</sub>}<sup>n</sup><sub>r=1</sub>

I found that it is progressing in increasing ascending order like +21, +23, +25 and so on

My latest answer is ${2081+[19+2(r-1)]}^\infty_{r=1}$. But it end up as 2100, 2102, 2104...

Is there any tips on this question?

Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is easier to subtract $2000$ to get
$$
\begin{split}
2000 &+ 100, 2000 + 121, 2000 + 144, 2000 + 169 + \ldots\\
     &= 2000 + 10^2, 2000 + 11^2, 2000 + 12^2, 2000 + 13^2 + \ldots
\end{split}
$$
so $a_i = 2000 + (10+i)^2$ for $i = 0,1, \ldots$

Comment: thank you for the clarification! I find that it is definitely easier but i would not have thought that without your help.